# Conversion of SQL Server to Oracle Select query

Tags: vb.net, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have a `Select` query:

```
SELECT 
    SAMPLE_NUMBER, SAMPLE_TYPE, STORAGE_ADDRESS, EXTERNAL_NUMBER 
FROM 
    SYSTMX2.TM2_SAMPLES
```

And what I need is to add two more columns with the results of some .Net syntax code so I would end up with something like"

```
SELECT 
    SAMPLE_NUMBER, SAMPLE_TYPE, STORAGE_ADDRESS, EXTERNAL_NUMBER, 
    SomeCodearound(STORAGE_ADDRESS) as RowPosition, 
    SomeCodearound(STORAGE_ADDRESS) as ColumnPosition 
FROM 
    SYSTMX2.TM2_SAMPLES
```

The row and column positions are based upon where they would fall in a 9 x 9 Grid. 9 numbers for columns across the top and 9 numbers as rows down the side. This would be a lab specimen box that would hold 81 vials. Every vial has a number from 1 to 81 and is the last three characters of the `STORAGE_ADDRESS` value similar to FR2-S01-R01-001 or FR2-S01-R01-081. Vial number 1 would be in column 1 and row 1; vial 81 in row 9 column 9.  My .net code for the row is to take the last three character of the `STORAGE_ADDRESS` and test with decimal.

```
TryParse(STORAGE_ADDRESS.Substring(STORAGE_ADDRESS.Length - 3), value)
```

and then take that value and convert with:

```
 CInt(Decimal.Truncate(((value+ 9 - 1) / 9))).
```

And the column code is:

```
 (value + 9) - (CInt(Decimal.Truncate(((value + 9 - 1) / 9))) * 9).
```

I need to make it into an inline `Select` statement that I can call from a web service to the Oracle server, I do not have any way to create anything database side. Right now what I do is to call the result recordset add a couple of columns and loop the results and add the values. I know there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Oracle query returns row and column positions:

```
select storage_address, 
    floor((to_number(substr(storage_address, 13, 3))-1)/9)+1 rowposition,
    mod(to_number(substr(storage_address, 13, 3))-1, 9)+1 colpostion
  from t
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1081) with test values.

Comment: FANTASTIC-- Thanks.  I know that I did not ask this in my original question but how can I but a lower case r or c after the numberic value?  So instead of 1 it would be 1r or 7c.  I know that conversions of Oracle valuse can be tricky.  Is is as simple to include the entire process in ()'s and just append?

Comment: Got it it was as simple as || 'c'  or || 'r'  Thanks again

Comment: Yes, simple concatenation, in the meantime I added it to [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1102).